# Does every peer need to be a node in BitTorrent when DHT is enabled?

Tags: bittorrent, dht

Does every peer become a DHT node every time it requests peers for a particular file? or do nodes exist independently of peers? in essence, how do you become a node? can you be a peer but not a node?

I'm sorry if the question is too simple (noob here) but I wasn't able to find an answer in any other place. The terminology I'm using is the same that is used [here](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html).

Comment: You may also want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332107/how-does-dht-in-torrents-work and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia

Comment: Thanks, but the question I'm asking arose after reading that info. I don't know if I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to *just* be a DHT node (a bittorrent client with DHT enabled but no torrents for instance). It is also possible to *just* be a bittorrent peer (a bittorrent client with DHT disabled and at least one torrent started).

Since the DHT is not tied to any specific torrent, running a (DHT) node will help out the global DHT network by aiding in routing and storing of peer-lists for random torrents.

Conversely, it's possible to be a bittorrent peer without participating in the DHT at all. One could even make DHT lookups for a torrent and still not participate in the DHT (by not responding to any requests for instance).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. Regarding the last paragraph, how would you make a bittorrent client ignore DHT requests, doesn't disabling DHT prevents you from being both a node and a peer? or were you assuming a hypothetical situation?

Comment: Assuming you write your own DHT implementation or modify an existing one.